# Programmatically refresh mapview user location

Tags: ios, mapkit, userlocation

I've a first view controller with a map view. showUserLocation is set to YES and it works perfectly. I then implemented the method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
```

to do some stuff when userLocation has been updated.
It works, but just the first time.
If I then switch to another view and then I come back to the mapviewcontroller the didUpdateUserLocation won't be fired again, although the user location is shown on the map.

Any suggestion?

thanks in advance,
Samuel

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 5, use `[mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeNone animated:NO]`.

Secondly — if you're calling in

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView
        didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)aUserLocation
```

method

```
[aMapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
```

don't do that if you want to move it to the user location.